# How to included nested standalone documents with subpreambles

Tags: standalone, preamble

I have discovered that standalone package can be used to combine multiple standalone documents into one document. I find this beneficial to split my work into multiple files and then compile certain sections as I please.

I have a report (parts, chapters, sections, subsections, etc.) where I want each subsection to have its own file. I also put tikz figures in their own file as well.

My files follow this general form.
For the "lower level" documents, the `subsection`s and `tikz` figures that contain actual content.

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles,sort,print]{standalone}

%include packages for this given document
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And for the `section` documents which only `include` the `subsections` content.

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles,sort,print]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Sub Section Name}
\subimport{subsections}{sub-section-name}
\end{document}
```

Finally, all "higher level" documents have this form. Below is a `main.tex` file in a "chapter" folder, where `main.tex` in the "sections" includes all the subsections.

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles,sort,print]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\subimport{chapter1}{main}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\subimport{chapter2}{main}
\end{document}
```

The issue is, I nest these higher level documents. The main document includes all parts, then inside the parts documents I include all chapters, etc.

My directory tree looks like this.

```
.
├── main.tex
├── part1
│   ├── chapter1
│   │   ├── main.tex
│   │   └── section1
│   │       └── main.tex
│   └── main.tex
└── part2
    ├── chapter1
    │   ├── main.tex
    │   └── section1
    │       └── main.tex
    └── main.tex
```

After I get to about three levels of nesting, this method breaks. I get an error that says "". I can workaround this error by removing the options on `standalone` which gets rid of my ability to include the preamble from the nested documents. This means I need to manually `include` any packages used in the "lower level" documents.

Is it possible to include the `subpreambles` for nested documents?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved after I deleted all .sta files and recompiled.